# Support SQL like filters for REST API collections

Tags: api, rest

REST API design seems to be simple when it comes to basic resources like `/product/{id}` or `/products` (collection).

In the real world though, you need to be able to filter your collections. For example display products where `price > 500` and `price < 1000`.

I guess my quesion is how do you model SQL like syntax into your REST API, so you could do complex collection filtering using `MAX`, `MIN`, `AND`, `OR`, `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=`, `sort by` with `asc` and `desc`?

How can you represent that logic cleanly with query string, so your API is still readable and doesn't look like this:

```
params[sorts][0][0]=usertotal&params[sorts][0][1]=ASC&params[fields][0][0]=id&params[fields][0][1]=uid&params[fields][0][2]=status&params[fields][0][3][t]=sum&params[fields][0][3][0]=total&params[fields][0][3][1]=usertotal&params[wheres][0][0][t]=and&params[wheres][0][0][0][t]=and&params[wheres][0][0][0][0][t]=cmp&params[wheres][0][0][0][0][0]=created&params[wheres][0][0][0][0][1]=>&params[wheres][0][0][0][0][2]=1.01.2013&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][t]=or&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][0][t]=cmp&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][0][0]=status&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][0][1]==&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][0][2]=1&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][1][t]=cmp&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][1][0]=status&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][1][1]==&params[wheres][0][0][0][1][1][2]=2&params[wheres][0][0][1][t]=cmp&params[wheres][0][0][1][0]=uid&params[wheres][0][0][1][1]==&params[wheres][0][0][1][2]=1.01.2013&params[limit]=10&params[offset]=0
```

If you look closer to query sample above, it uses array to transfer/encode filters from client to API so that data could be easily extracted from query string and processed on the API side. At the same time it completely ruins readability, make API totally useless without SDK.

I'm struggling to find the right balance between structuring complex collection filters using query string on the client and keeping API clean..